# Session bean gets lost on HTTPS-DNS combo

Tags: jsf, ssl, https, websphere

I have an application that goes like this

F5 load balancer - IHS(a&b) - Websphere 7(a&b) - JSF

When i try to log into my app via https-dns (which works perfectly fine via http) the session bean gets lost, I'm out of ideas of what could possibly be causing this as if you access the app via https-dns in firefox or chrome the bean its there and everything is beautiful, but the bean gets lost (null) in IE7/8.

Besides (i dont know if its relevant or no) if you access via https-ip the app works just fine in IE7/8.

Its worth mentioning that I have no control over the configuration of any of the layers, im just the developer and im trying to figure it out since (obviously) all the people of the layer's support tell me "its not our problem, its your app" without even a brief check of the conf, despite that the very same EAR gets deployed to two identical environments (DEV-TESTING) and only in the latter is acting weird.

Any light on this will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So when you access in IE via DNS, can you see that the cookie is there in the browser, maybe under the IP instead? Also, can you watch the HTTP request & response headers to see what, if any, Set-Cookie is returned? Finally, do you have access to even look at the WebSphere configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let anyone know what the problem was:

Turns out the problem was that my session cookie wasnt been stored in IE, and after a lot of google magic, I found out that **the DNS cannot have underscores on it**

And changing my DNS from

**mysite_testing**

to

**mysitetesting**

solved the issue.

I couldnt find anything "official" but here are some links that could be useful.

[Social MSDN A](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/666533ab-6634-4be5-a6d9-9b7239ed967f)
  [Social MSDN B](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/8e876e9e-b223-4f84-a5d1-1eda2c2bbdf4)
  [SmartBear](http://blog.smartbear.com/software-quality/bid/170474/Internet-Explorer-Eats-Cookies-with-Underscores-in-the-Hostname)
  [Wikipedia RFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname)